# Line integral of the vector infinitesimal length of a line

Tags: integration, physics, curves, vector-fields, line-integrals

I'm studying magnetic field and the mechanic actions that a vectorial field $\mathbf{B}$ impose to a circuit.

Now, when it comes to the resulting force on a closed circuit (closed line) with a current $I$ in a uniform magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$, it uses the formula:
$$
\mathbf{F} = I\oint_{\gamma}\operatorname{d}\mathbf{l}\,\times\mathbf{B}
$$
where the $\operatorname{d}\mathbf{l}$ stands for the infinitesimal vectorial length of the circuit, so that:
$$
\oint_{\gamma}\operatorname{d}l = L(\gamma)
$$
where $L(\gamma)$ is the total length of the closed curve. 
Because of $\mathbf{B}$ uniformity, one can write:
$$
\mathbf{F} = I\left[\oint_{\gamma}\operatorname{d}\mathbf{l}\right]\,\times\mathbf{B}
$$
as $\mathbf{B}$ doesn't depend on the position, so can be taken out from the integral. Here comes the problematic step. It's said that 
$$
\oint_{\gamma}\operatorname{d}\mathbf{l}=0
$$
for every closed curve. 
Even if I can understand heuristically why that integral should be zero, I cannot figure out what mathematical process bring to this result. I mean, how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accept getting $\mathbf B$ get out of the integral, the remaining integral is simply adding vectors all of them lying along a loop. Consider a parametrization of $\gamma$, $(x(t),y(t))$ for which $(x(0),y(0))=(x(T),y(T))$

$$\oint_{\gamma}\operatorname{d}\mathbf{l}=\oint_{\gamma}(dx,dy)=\left(\int_0^T\dot x(t)dt,\int_0^T\dot y(t)dt\right)=\left(\left[x(t)\right]_0^T,\right[y(t)\left]_0^T\right)=(0,0)$$